# What is the right way to convert saved tensorflow model to tensorflow Lite

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I have a saved tensorflow model the same as all models in the [model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md).

I want to convert it to tesorflow lite, I find the following way from tensorflow github (my tensorflw version is 2):

```
!wget http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz 
# extract the downloaded file
!tar -xzvf ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz
```

> 

```
!pip install tf-nightly
import tensorflow as tf
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model('ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8/saved_model')
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.experimental_new_converter = True

converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
tflite_model = converter.convert()

open("m.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

But the output and input shape of the converted model don't match the original model, check the following:

- **Original Model Input & Output shape**

[image]

- **Converted Model Input & Output shape**

[image]

So there is a problem here! the input / output shape should be matched the original model!
Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Tensorflow github issues, I used their answer to solve my problem.
[Link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42114#issuecomment-671593386)

Their approach:

```
!pip install tf-nightly
import tensorflow as tf

## TFLite Conversion
model = tf.saved_model.load("saved_model")
concrete_func = model.signatures[tf.saved_model.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY]
concrete_func.inputs[0].set_shape([1, 300, 300, 3])
tf.saved_model.save(model, "saved_model_updated", signatures={"serving_default":concrete_func})
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir='saved_model_updated', signature_keys=['serving_default'])

converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
tflite_model = converter.convert()

## TFLite Interpreter to check input shape
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_content=tflite_model)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

# Test the model on random input data.
input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
print(input_shape)
```

> [  1 300 300   3]

Thank you [MeghnaNatraj](https://github.com/MeghnaNatraj)

Comment: What happens when `interpreter.invoke()` is called? I got `RuntimeError: Container __per_step_0 does not exist. (Could not find resource: __per_step_0/_tensor_arraysTensorArrayV3_0)
  (while executing 'TensorArrayScatterV3' via Eager)Node number 237 (TfLiteFlexDelegate) failed to invoke.
` after calling `invoke()` on the `interpreter` when I use the `tflite` model created in this way. Although already available `tflite` models (from https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/hosted_models) don't throw this error. I have converted a `ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29`  model trained on custom data.

Answer (score 0):

The shape of both models input and output should be the same as shown below

If the model is already in saved_model format, you the code below

```
# if you are using same model
export_dir = 'ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8/saved_model'
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(export_dir)
```

if your model is in Keras format, use the format below

```
# if it's a keras model 
model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(weights="imagenet", input_shape= (224, 224, 3))
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
```

In both cases, the intention is to get the converter.

I don't have the saved_model, so I will use keras model and convert it to saved_model format just use the Keras model format as an example

```
import pathlib #to use path
model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(weights="imagenet", input_shape= (224, 224, 3))
export_dir = 'imagenet/saved_model'
tf.saved_model.save(model, export_dir) #convert keras to saved model

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(export_dir)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]  #you can also optimize for size or latency OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE, OPTIMIZE_FOR_LATENCY
tflite_model = converter.convert()

#save the model
tflite_model_file = pathlib.Path('m.tflite')
tflite_model_file.write_bytes(tflite_model)

tflite_interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path= 'm.tflite') #you can load the content with model_content=tflite_model

# get shape of tflite input and output
input_details = tflite_interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = tflite_interpreter.get_output_details()
print("Input: {}".format( input_details[0]['shape']))
print("Output:{}".format(output_details[0]['shape']))

# get shape of the origin model
print("Input:  {}".format( model.input.shape))
print("Output: {}".format(model.output.shape))
```

For the tflite: I have this

[image]

For the Original Model I have this

[image]

You will see the shape of both `tflite` and `keras` model are the same

Comment: My model is saved_model.pb not model.h5, SO it is not keras model

Comment: edit my question and adding the model link, please confirm if you got matched input output
http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz

Comment: @H.H it seem something is wrong with the saved_model . I get this `None is only supported in the 1st dimension. Tensor 'input_tensor' has invalid shape '[1, None, None, 3]'`  I tried another test saved model and it worked fine

Comment: So I updated to code , and convert Keras model to saved_model and used the saved_model version. It still worked as expected. So something is wrong with the downloaded saved_model format you are using

Comment: can u try with this model http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz

Comment: This saved model from the Tensorflow github page NOT my model

Comment: I have the same issue with a keras model. I am testing the solution from MeghnaNatraj as reported by @H.H. Will report if this also works in this case...

Answer (score 0):

Just reshape your input tensor.

You can use the `resize_tensor_input` function, like this:

```
interpreter.resize_tensor_input(input_index=0, tensor_size=[1, 640, 640, 3])
```

Now you input shape will be: `[1, 640, 640, 3]`.