# tensorflow-lite model output shape isn't same as original model output shape

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, inference, quantization, tflite

I'm comparing the performance of two models that I've trained.

The first model takes an input of size (1536, 512, 3), which represents 1536 windows of data with each window having 512 window size and 3 features.

The model's output shape is (1536, 512, 1), which means it provides predictions for each of the 1536 windows, with each prediction having a single value.

**Issue:**
I've converted the model to TFLite format to optimize its deployment. However, when I ran the converted model on the same input data, I noticed that the output shape has changed to (1, 512, 1).

This is confusing to me because I expected the TFLite model to produce the same output shape as the original model, i.e., (1536, 512, 1).

Can someone explain why the output shape has changed and how I can convert it back to the original shape?

Code used:

```py
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
input_shape = input_details[0]["shape"]

output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
input_data = np.array(data_windows, dtype=input_details[0]["dtype"]) #shape: (1536, 512, 3)

interpreter.tensor(input_data)
interpreter.invoke()

output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]["index"]) #shape: (1, 512, 1)
```

I tried proposed solutions on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63325216/what-is-the-right-way-to-convert-saved-tensorflow-model-to-tensorflow-lite) but didn't work for me.

Comment: have you checked your model with netron.app? Are you sure the outputs are different?